# What are the available variables in Atom editor and how can I use them?

Tags: atom-editor

I'm exploring the Atom editor and trying to set up some Snippets. I would like to know if there are variables that I can use to insert things like the Author's name, file creation date, etc.

I looked around and since Atom is patterned after Sublime, I tried to use $TM_FULLNAME but it didn't seem to work. Where might I find the variables that Atom exposes (if any)?

Regards,

Rene' Robinson

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a late answer, but currently doesn't look like it does support this. Tried looking through [the snippets code on GitHub](https://github.com/atom/snippets), but so far, not seeing variables

(at least as of today and version d74e73364c5fd48a73524ae28f6fb442c7e6e95d of snippets project)